# Postgres WITH subquery using relation by id

Tags: postgresql, subquery, common-table-expression

I know, this query (it's incorrect, just an example) can be written in other way. But, I'm interested in using WITH when there is a such relation `m.user_id = u.id`. Is it possible? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html - Looks like WITH is only used for prepared data, not dynamic.

```
with last_message as (
  select m.message 
  from messages m 
  where m.user_id = u.id 
  order by m.id desc 
  limit 1
)
select u.*, last_message
from users u
where last_message = 'some_message';
```

P.S. Don't understand, why Postgres restrict us to have variable for subquery (as statements that would be executed), so we could easily use this variable in select and where clauses.
Currently, I have to copy subquery from select clause and use it in where clause(

Comment: I don't understand what your question ist. Your code is invalid because `last_message` is a **table** alias in your example. Your final SELECT is equivalent to `select u.*, some_other_table from users u where some_other_table = 'some_string'` - would that make sense to you? There are also no "variables" in a query. I am not sure what you are referring to.

Comment: This is extremely unclear. It is not clear what you are trying to ask. What does "when there is a such relation" (presumably, when there is such a condition) mean? What is stopping you from doing what you want to do? What does anything in this post have to do with it? Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Debug questions require a [mre]. Please ask exactly 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. [ask] [Help] Please put everything needed to ask in your post, not  just at a link; quote with credit & relate to your question.

Comment: A CTE introduces a table name not a table alias. `select ( 1-row 1-column subquery ) from ...` is legal. So `with lm as ( 1-row 1-column subquery ) select (select * from lm) from ...` is legal. A table alias (correlation name) denotes a quantified/arbitrary row, which is why you can dot it with a column in the row & get the value for that column in the row.

Comment: No idea what you mean by "prepared data, not dynamic" but there is so much you can do with common table expressions, that it's hard to believe your question will get an answer that covers all these (very) different possibilities.

Comment: A WITH introduces a name for a table, not a non-table.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right your *problematic* query – with the subquery *copied* in the `WHERE` clause is something like the one below

```
select u.*, m.last_message
from users u
cross join lateral (
  select  m.message last_message
  from messages m 
  where m.user_id = u.id 
  order by m.id desc 
  limit 1
) m  
where (
  select m.message 
  from messages m 
  where m.user_id = u.id 
  order by m.id desc 
  limit 1
) = 'some_message';
```

This is indeed not the preferred solution. Not only a violation of the `DRY` principle, but also the subquery may effectively be executed *twice* for each user.

Unfortunately (or better unsurprisingly) you can’t use the `WITH` subquery *correlated* with some other table as in your example. This lead immediately to

```
 ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "u"
```

What is the alternative? Define the `CTE` so that it produces the *last message* for all users and join it with the query. Here an example using `distinct on`

```
with last_message as (
  select distinct on (m.user_id) user_id, m.message last_message 
  from messages m 
  order by m.user_id, m.id desc 
)
select u.*, m.last_message
from users u
join last_message m on u.id = m.user_id
where m.last_message = 'some_message';
```

As another option you may define a view filtering the *last message* and use it in a join

```
create view last_message as
  select distinct on (m.user_id) user_id, m.message last_message 
  from messages m 
  order by m.user_id, m.id desc;
 
select u.*, m.last_message
from users u
join last_message m on u.id = m.user_id
where m.last_message = 'some_message';
```